# Confused about Simple Asyntask app

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple **AsynTask** sample. I can't make it run. When I click the **Button**, **ProgressDialog** is supposed to be  displayed. But nothing happens. I don't get any **Exceptions**. Probably I'm missing out a few things.

```
ProgressDialog dialog=null;
Button btnstart;
MyAsynTask mytask;
static final int SLEEP_TIME=(15*1000)/100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnstart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mytask=new MyAsynTask();
                mytask.execute();

            }
        });

    }


public class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.show();



    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if(isCancelled()){

                break;
            }
            else {
                publishProgress(i);

            }
        }
        return null;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialog.setProgress(values[0]);

    }
```

Comment: could You Show Your isCancelled() method ?

Comment: Remove all super calls. Counting to 100 will be done before you see the dialog. What is in onPostExecute()?

Comment: @ greenapps Plase post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right.
Use Logs in onPreExecute(),doInBackBackground() to see what's happening actually.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more method to Asynctask class

```
onPostExcute()
{
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

OnPost method in the asynctask excutes after doinbackgournd method there you need to dismiss the dialog